# Show that $2\text{rk($\tau$)} \leq \text{dim($V$)}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $\text{dim($V$)} < \infty$ and suppose that $\tau \in \mathfrak{L}(V)$ satisfies $\tau^{2} = 0$. Show that $2\text{rk($\tau$)} \leq \text{dim($V$)}$.

By Rank-Nullity Theorem we know that $\text{dim($V$)} = \text{rk($\tau$)} + \text{null($\tau$)}$. Since $\tau: V \longrightarrow V$, then if $\tau^{2} = 0$ does it mean that $\text{Ker($\tau$)} = V$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\ker \tau = V$, then $\tau = 0$ and this is trivial.

This result follows immediately from Sylvester's inequality, which states that 
$$ \operatorname{rank}\Phi + \operatorname{rank}\Psi - n \leq \operatorname{rank}\Phi\Psi
$$
for any lienar $\Phi,\Psi:V \to V$. Substituting $\Phi=\Psi = \tau$ yields $2\operatorname{rank} \tau \leq n$, as desired.